# Реализация метода поиска в списке из объектов класса

Tags: python, ооп, классы, list, методы

```
import sys


class Students():
    studBase = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.lastName = input('Last Name: ')
        self.yearOfBirth = input('Year of birth: ')
        self.year = input('Year: ')
        self.group = input('Group: ')
        self.faculty = input('Faculty: ')
        self.__class__.studBase.append(self)

    def search(self):
        param = input('Last name: ')
        for param in Students.studBase:
            if param in Students.studBase:
                return print(f'{self.lastName} {self.faculty}')
            else:
                return print('Error')
    #def sort(self):
        

    def show(self):
        print(f"{student.lastName}  {student.year} {student.yearOfBirth} {student.group} {student.faculty}")

while(True):
    choice = input('Select from the list'
               + '\n1 - Add student'
               + '\n2 - Search'
               + '\n3 - Sort'
               + '\n4 - Show'
               + '\n5 - Exit'
               + '\n'
               )
    if choice == '1':
        n = int(input('Add:'))
        for s in range(n):
            student = Students()
    elif choice == '2':
        student.search()
 #   elif choice =='3':
        #student.sort()
    elif choice == '4':
        for student in Students.studBase:
            student.show()
    elif choice == '5':
        sys.exit()
```

При попытке вызова метода search() и поиска по критерию, возвращает только последний элемент списка. **Не понимаю в чем проблема**.

Answer (score 2):

```
for param in Students.studBase:
    if param in Students.studBase:
        return print(f'{self.lastName} {self.faculty}')
    else:
        return print('Error')
```

Что-то у вас и цикл задвоился и конструкция `return print` ещё (которая вернёт `None`). Нужно примерно так:

```
for param in Students.studBase:
    print(f'{param.lastName} {param.faculty}')
return
```

Если вам всё же обязательно нужно печатать ошибку в случае, если ничего не нашлось, тогда, например, так:

```
found = False
for param in Students.studBase:
    print(f'{param.lastName} {param.faculty}')
    found = True
if not found:
    print('Error')
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Вчера покумекав и обратившись за помощью. Пришла к следующему ответу. Возможно, он не является синтаксически "красивым" и взрослые дяди начнут ругаться, но вот что получилось:
**Добавила ещё сортировку по фамилии**

```
class Students():
    studBase = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.lastName = input('Last Name: ')
        self.yearOfBirth = input('Year of birth: ')
        self.year = int(input('Year: '))
        self.group = input('Group: ')
        self.faculty = input('Faculty: ')
        self.__class__.studBase.append(self)

    def search(self):
        param = input('Last name: ')
        for i in Students.studBase:
            if i.lastName == param:
                print(f'{i.lastName} {i.faculty}')
                
    def show(self):
        print(f"{student.lastName}  {student.year} {student.yearOfBirth} {student.group} {student.faculty}")
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.lastName, self.yearOfBirth, self.year,self.group,self.faculty))
    def sort(self):
        print(Students.studBase)#Сначала вывод состояния списка на момент заполнености
        return sorted(Students.studBase, key=lambda self: self.year)#возврат отсортированного
        
while(True):
    choice = input('Select from the list'
               + '\n1 - Add student'
               + '\n2 - Search'
               + '\n3 - Sort'
               + '\n4 - Show'
               + '\n5 - Exit'
               + '\n'
               )
    if choice == '1':
        n = int(input('Add:'))
        for s in range(n):
            student = Students()
    elif choice == '2':
        student.search()
    elif choice =='3':
        print(student.sort())
    elif choice == '4':
        for student in Students.studBase:
            student.show()
```